# What exactly is happening to acceleration when direction changes?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, vectors

As direction changes i know that acceleration occurs but what exactly is happening to it, is it increasing acceleration, decreasing acceleration, constant acceleration, negative acceleration or positive acceleration ???

Comment: It depends. In fact, when velocity changes direction, acceleration might as well.

Comment: Acceleration is a [_vector._](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) There is no "negative or positive" except in the special case where the motion is constrained to follow a straight line. If the direction of motion can change, then acceleration, velocity, and position all must be represented as vectors.

Comment: As direction of what changes? What is referenced by the word "it"? Please edit the question itself to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, you can't just change this to a new question. Please just open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Direction of motion changes due to acceleration but there is not any compulsion that there should or should not be any change in acceleration when direction changes.

For example when we throw a object in air at some angle (parabolic motion) then gravity is a downward force which is constant in both direction and magnitude but still direction of motion of object changes continuously.
But in circular motion (example earth around sun) the direction of motion of earth changes and simultaneously direction of centripetal force also changes.

So we can't decide upon acceleration from direction of motion.

Answer (score 0):

very good question.
we know that speed is a vector. for changing a vector, it needs to be added to another vector.
this question, is a very good example to talk about steady state and transient state.
but what are steady state and transient state? well for the sake of this question, steady state means when the direction change is over. meaning that "only" looking at the starting direction and ending direction, but nothing that happens in between. for example, let's assume we have a car going east at 50 km/h (80 miles/h) and it takes a turn and goes north at the same speed.
[image: car state after and before truning in the time "T"]

T is the time taken for our change to happen. you have V1 vector and V2 vectors as the starting and ending speeds.

[image: vector equations]

as you can see, in the time "T" the average acceleration changes the speed vector from V1 to V2. there are a lot of ways that the car could have done that (turning normally, drifting, etc...) whatever happens, belongs to the transient state, and the average acceleration remains the same, given as:
$$\overrightarrow{a}_{avg}={{\overrightarrow{V_2}-\overrightarrow{V_1}}\over{T}}$$